# SQL Functions - factorial

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a beginner in SQL Functions. 
What is the best way to create a function for factorial in SQL Server- Say 10!

Comment: Does it really need to be SQL?  Seems to me there would be a ton of other better options out there.

Comment: Thank you for the response
Yea it has to be SQL. I am learning Functions on SQL Server
No its not a homework, I am doing self practice by solving a functions sample paper I found online

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Factorial ( @iNumber int )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i  int

    IF @iNumber <= 1
        SET @i = 1
    ELSE
        SET @i = @iNumber * dbo.Factorial( @iNumber - 1 )
RETURN (@i)
END
```

Comment: I think using `BIGINT` here would be an improvement

Comment: `BIGINT` will overflow 21!  You can achieve up to 33! with `DECIMAL(38,0)`.

Answer (score 18):

A non recursive way

```
;With Nums As
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
FROM sys.objects
)
SELECT  POWER(10.0, SUM(LOG10(RN)))
FROM Nums
WHERE RN <= 10
```

And a recursive way

```
declare @target int
set @target=10;

WITH N AS
     (SELECT 1 AS i,
           1 AS f

     UNION ALL

     SELECT i+1,
            f*(i+1)
     FROM   N
     WHERE  i < @target
     )
SELECT f FROM N
WHERE i=@target
```

Comment: Using the non-recursive SQL, there is a precision issue with `LOG10(RN)` starting at 17!.  It works for 16! and less.  17! is off by 0.6.  18! is off by 17.  19! is off by 300.  20! is off by 6100.  21! is off by 164000.  22! is off by 4620000.  Etc.  The recursive SQL is accurate to 29! if you `CAST(1 as decimal(32,0)) AS f` and `CAST(f*(i+1) as decimal(32,0))`.

Answer (score 4):

-- Iterative method.
-- Why Iterative? It is simpler and faster.
-- For @N from 0 to 20 this gives an exact result.
-- 21 will give an overflow.

```
DECLARE @N Bigint = 20
DECLARE @F Bigint = 1
WHILE @N > 0 BEGIN
  SET @F = @f*@n
  SET @N = @N-1
END
SELECT @F AS FACTORIAL
```

-- Change the datatype to float and you can get the factorial up to 170.
-- 171 will result in an overflow.
-- Remark the result will only be accurate over a limited number of positions.

```
DECLARE @N FLOAT = 170
DECLARE @F FLOAT = 1
WHILE @N > 0 BEGIN
  SET @F = @f*@n
  SET @N = @N-1
END
SELECT @F AS FACTORIAL
```

-- Ben

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WITH MYCTE AS(
 SELECT VAL=1,NUM =6 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT VAL=VAL*NUM,NUM = (NUM -1)
 FROM MYCTE
 WHERE NUM > 1
)                  
SELECT VAL FROM MYCTE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
create function Fact(@num int)
returns bigint
as
begin
declare @i int = 1

 while @num>1
 begin
  set @i = @num *  @i
  set @num=@num-1
  end

return @i
end

select dbo.Fact(5)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider also writing a few words on how you came up to this solution and do not forget to highlight the code chunks.

Answer (score 1):

... for my Set-based method:

```
DECLARE @n int=11, @f bigint=1;

WITH 
t(n,f) AS (SELECT TOP(@n) 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))+1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) *
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))+1)
     FROM sys.all_columns
     UNION SELECT 1, f=CASE WHEN @n=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
SELECT @f=@f*f
FROM t
WHERE n%2=@n%2 OR f=0;


SELECT @f AS FACTORIAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late here, but it's worth noting that the recursive way that Martin posted does not work for 0.

This will (forgive me, I was having issues posting the code):

---

```
declare @target int=3;

WITH N AS
(SELECT 1 AS i, 
        1 AS f
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i+1,
        f*(i+1)
 FROM N
 WHERE  i < @target),
N0 AS
(SELECT f FROM N WHERE i=@target UNION SELECT 0)
SELECT MAX(f) FROM N0
```

And for the way, way faster version:

```
declare @target int=5;

WITH N AS
(SELECT 1 AS i, 
        1 AS f
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i+1,
        f*(i+1)
 FROM N
 WHERE i < @target),
N0 AS
(SELECT f FROM N WHERE i=@target UNION SELECT f=CASE WHEN @target=0 THEN 0 END)
SELECT f FROM N0
WHERE f>=0
```

This is much faster because I lose the MAX() function which, just like top 1, causes a DISTINCT sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other method to [calculate factorial value of an integer in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-factorial-calculation-mathematical-function.aspx)

```
 create function sqlFactorial (@int int)
 returns int
 begin
  declare @factorial bigint = 1
  select @factorial = @factorial * i from dbo.NumbersTable(1,@int,1)
  return @factorial
 end
```

You need to use a [SQL numbers table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx) for this solution. 
The Select statement updates the declared integer variable for each row in the FROM part with multiplying it with the ordered integer values

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with an approximation, use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

```
create table #temp (value int)

insert into #temp values (5),(6),(7),(8)

select 
    value,
    sqrt(2*3.14*value)*power((value/2.718),value) --stirling's approx.
from #temp
```

Note that you will have to make a case for 0!, if needed.

Comment: If @Jason literally means a user-defined function in sql-server, you can't define a table inside of a function, besides a table variable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267804/create-drop-and-insert-a-temp-table-in-a-user-defined-function

Answer (score 0):

You asked which is the *best* way to create a function for factorial in SQL Server. As always, that depends on the context. But if you truly mean it in the generic sense, where performance matters, the best way to go is without a doubt to implement it as a CLR user-defined function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017

You can of course implement the function itself in whatever language you fancy. And a long/bigint doesn't really cut it for a factorial function (a bigint can only fit up to 20!, 21! is arithmetic overflow).

Answer (score 0):

/* Print Factorial Sequence*/

```
WITH MYCTE AS(
 SELECT VAL=1,NUM =1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT VAL=VAL*(NUM+1),NUM = (NUM +1)
 FROM MYCTE
 WHERE NUM < 11
)                  
SELECT VAL FROM MYCTE
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

MS-SQL: Factorial from 0 to 88:

```
with tb1 as (
select 10000000 as b, 1 as n, 
0 as t18, 0 as t17, 0 as t16, 0 as t15, 0 as t14, 0 as t13, 0 as t12, 0 as t11, 0 as t10, 0 as t9, 0 as t8, 0 as t7, 0 as t6, 0 as t5, 0 as t4, 0 as t3, 0 as t2, 0 as t1, 1 as t0
union all 
select 
tb1.b,
tb1.n + 1,
(tb1.t18 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t17 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t16 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t15 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t14 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t13 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b,
((tb1.t17 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t16 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t15 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t14 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t13 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t16 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t15 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t14 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t13 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t15 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t14 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t13 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t14 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t13 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t13 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t12 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t11 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t10 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t9 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t8 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t7 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t6 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b, 
((tb1.t5 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t4 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t3 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t2 * tb1.n) + ((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)/tb1.b)%tb1.b,
((tb1.t1 * tb1.n) + (tb1.t0 * tb1.n) / tb1.b)%tb1.b,
(tb1.t0 * tb1.n) % tb1.b
from tb1 where tb1.n < 89
)
, t2 as (
select  tb1.n - 1 as N,
        FORMAT(tb1.t18, '0000000') + 
        FORMAT(tb1.t17, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t16, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t15, '0000000') + 
        FORMAT(tb1.t14, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t13, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t12, '0000000') +
        FORMAT(tb1.t11, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t10, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t9, '0000000') +
        FORMAT(tb1.t8, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t7, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t6, '0000000') +
        FORMAT(tb1.t5, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t4, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t3, '0000000') +
        FORMAT(tb1.t2, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t1, '0000000') + FORMAT(tb1.t0, '0000000') as FACT
from tb1
)

select  t2.N, SUBSTRING(t2.FACT, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', t2.FACT+'.'), LEN(t2.FACT))
from t2
order by t2.N
```

Comment: Add an explanation to what this code does so that your answer is more valuable.