# Create, drop and insert a temp table in a user-defined function

Tags: sql-server, function

I am trying to create a function as per my requirements.

But, when am creating or drop `#tempTable`, it is giving an error as:

> invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'drop object' within a function

My understanding is that we can't have `create`, `drop` or `insert` operations on `#temptable` in a function.

Is that correct?

My SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RT_ResultFunction]
(
    Id VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS @RT_ResultFunction TABLE 
(   
    Id VARCHAR(20)
    , Name varchar(20)
    ,Balance Int
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL  
       DROP TABLE #tempTable

    SELECT Id, COUNT(Balance) 
    INTO  #tempTable
    'Balance' FROM Table1

    INSERT  @RT_ResultFunction 
        SELECT T1.ID,T1,NAME,T2,Balance 
        FROM    Table2 T1, 
                #tempTable T2
        WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Bit confused about your SQL. How to you select from #tempTable after you've dropped it - its never recreated.

Comment: If you want help solving this issue, please explain the point of the #temptable inside the function. Also what to do with the Id parameter.

Comment: Please stop using implicit joins. They are a SQl antipattern.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is correct - you cannot have side effecting statements:

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085(v=sql.80).aspx

> The statements in a BEGIN...END block cannot have any side effects.
>   Function side effects are any permanent changes to the state of a
>   resource that has a scope outside the function such as a modification
>   to a database table. The only changes that can be made by the
>   statements in the function are changes to objects local to the
>   function, such as local cursors or variables. Modifications to
>   database tables, operations on cursors that are not local to the
>   function, sending e-mail, attempting a catalog modification, and
>   generating a result set that is returned to the user are examples of
>   actions that cannot be performed in a function.

What you would find, even without your `DROP` statement, is that any attempt to access a temp table will give you the message (such as a `SELECT ... INTO #TMP`):

> Cannot access temporary tables from within a function

As @Dems points out, you can use table variables. Because these are variables, they are scoped within the function, and therefore aren't side effecting.

Your function might run as:

```
...

BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempTable table (id varchar(20), rows int)

    insert @tempTable
    SELECT Id, COUNT(Balance) 
    FROM Table1

    INSERT  @RT_ResultFunction 
        SELECT T1.ID,T1,NAME,T2,Balance 
        FROM    Table2 T1, 
                @tempTable T2
        WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID

    RETURN END
```

Not tested or anything, but you get the gist.

Comment: But you can use table variables.  Which would be a useful fact to add to your answer to assist the OP in resolving his problem *(rather than just knowing why it's a problem)* ;)

Comment: After I read the MSDN Documentation, I asked myself : is it possible to modify real data from a table (`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`) by calling a `Stored Procedure` in your `function` ? I suppose that you can't, but I'd rather be sure that an error will be produced. Could you tell me if you know that ? :)

Comment: @LukeMarlin You can't call stored procedures from a UDF because stored procedures CAN cause side effects and functions are not allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you need a #temp table in this function or why it's a multi-statement TVF in the first place. The following will be much more efficient (though I don't understand the purpose of the `@Id` parameter):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RT_ResultFunction]
(
    @Id VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT T2.ID, T2.NAME, T1.Balance
    FROM
    (
      SELECT ID, Balance = COUNT(Balance) 
        FROM dbo.Table1 
        GROUP BY ID
    ) AS T1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
  );
```

As Jon pointed out, I *think* it could also be re-written as follows, and it's actually how I started writing it, but I have no way to confirm if either of these actually returns the data you're trying to return:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RT_ResultFunction]
(
    @Id VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT T2.ID, T2.NAME, Balance = COUNT(T1.Balance)
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS T1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    GROUP BY T2.ID, T2.NAME
  );
```

Comment: True - the temp table is a bit of a "luxury" in this case, but its a useful point to cover in any case. (also you need an alias on the inner count col).

Comment: @Jon ID and Name come from different tables. I don't know the schema or the data so I tried to remain true to the original query.

Answer (score -2):

Remove # instead use @
I have not tested other aspect