# How will you find the sum of numbers in between two numbers.

Tags: sql, sql-server

How will you find the sum of numbers in between two numbers. For example, the sum of numbers between 1 and 5 is 9 which is  2 + 3 + 4.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sum of integers from 1 to N equals N*(N+1) / 2, it's pretty straightforward:

```
create function sumBetween(@p_Lower integer, @p_Upper integer) returns int
as
begin
  return ((@p_Upper-1) * @p_Upper)/2 - (@p_Lower * (@p_Lower+1))/2
end

select dbo.sumBetween(1,5)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04302/1)

**EDIT** fixed fencepost error in fiddle

Comment: Your fiddle returns 14...

Comment: I had a off-by-one error - I fixed it yesterday in the answer, but forgot the fiddle. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical formula:
((a + b)*n/2) - a - b

where n is the count of digits between a and b including a and b

If a = 2 and b = 5 then

((2 + 5)*4/2) - 2 - 5 = 7

Comment: FYI, if you write this all in terms of `a` and `b`, then simplify, you get http://stackoverflow.com/a/18276578/644969

Comment: @cadrell0 Nope both are not equivalent. Even if you look at sql fiddle demo it returns 14 where as it should return 9. If a = 1 and b  = 5 then my logic will return ((1+5)*5/2)-1-5 = 9 which is correct. If you take p_lower = 2 and p_Upper = 5 the function you mentioned returns 12 where as it should return 7 which is what my formula is returning.

Comment: The fiddle has a typo that was corrected in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

((Xn+1)*Xn/2) - (X1-1)*X1/2  - Xn - X1

Xn=5
X1=1
  ((5+1)*5/2) - (1-1)*1/2 - 5 -1 = 9

Xn=5
X1=2
    ((5+1)*5/2) - (2-1)*2/2 - 5 -2 = 7

You might need to tweak it a bit...

Comment: How does that work for say 2 to 5 where the correct answer is 7 but it looks like your formula returns 10.5 (2+5)*2.5 - 2 - 5

Comment: I wrote, "need to tweak it a bit"...

Comment: correct will try this

Comment: I modified the equation, give it a try, I am sure I missed something, but still SHOULD be easy to modify it

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code for a factorial in SQL like those in [SQL Functions - factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504932/sql-functions-factorial) to build a function that you want.

Change the line for `i * (i+1)` to `i + (i+1)` and you should have a solution.

Comment: This is a well established mathematical principal that can be solved with some very simple arithmetic.  Writing a recursive function for this over-complicates the problem and is not efficient at all.

Comment: I agree. Reading up on it from the other solutions and a quick skim of my math text.  Thanks.