# How to find factorial for given number without using * symbol in T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got factorial value by using * symbol:

```
declare @given_number int=5;
declare @fact int=1;

while(@given_number > 1)
begin
    set @fact = @fact * @given_number;
    set @given_number = @given_number - 1;
end

select @fact as 'Factorial is '
```

But now I want to get same factorial value without using * symbol

Can you please help me by giving the correct query?

Comment: Why the limitation that the `*` symbol can't be used? Just seems completely arbitrary and of no practical value. Maybe you would also like answers to avoid the letter `S`?

Comment: My answer here anyway https://stackoverflow.com/a/3505072/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree that requirements are somehow odd. But let's treat it as challenge for some creative way.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is very easy to achieve with [`CHOOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh213019(v=sql.110)):

```
declare @given_number int=5;

SELECT 
  @given_number AS given_number,
  CHOOSE(@given_number
    ,1
    ,2
    ,6
    ,24
    ,120
    ,720
    ,5040
    ,40320
    ,362880
    ,3628800
    ,39916800
    ,479001600
    ,6227020800
    ,87178291200
    ,1307674368000
    ,20922789888000
    ,355687428096000
    ,6402373705728000
    ,121645100408832000
    ,2432902008176640000) AS factorial;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67da646d9ba69d7979f46fe00e69d8f7)**

---

**EDIT (fun part):**

> *But will you accept Martin Smith's challenge excluding the letter S?*

Today I recall that `CASE/IIF` could be nested only 10 times :)

```
declare @given_number int=5;

PRINT CONCAT('For ' ,@given_number, ' factorial = ',
IIF(@given_number=1,1
,IIF(@given_number=2,2
,IIF(@given_number=3,6
,IIF(@given_number=4,24
,IIF(@given_number=5,120
,IIF(@given_number=6,720
,IIF(@given_number=7,5040
,IIF(@given_number=8,40320
,IIF(@given_number=9,362880
,IIF(@given_number=10,3628800, -1)))))))))));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5eed15dc0b0d194b5033ed596b17dd3d)**

**EDIT2:**

One way to circumvent `IIF` limitation is to use original query with dynamic SQL + exchange `S` with `CHAR(83)`:

```
declare @t NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'declare @given_number int=5;' +  CHAR(83) + 'ELECT   given_number = @given_number,   factorial = CHOO'+  CHAR(83) +'E(@given_number    ,1    ,2    ,6    ,24    ,120    ,720    ,5040    ,40320    ,362880    ,3628800    ,39916800    ,479001600    ,6227020800    ,87178291200    ,1307674368000    ,20922789888000    ,355687428096000    ,6402373705728000    ,121645100408832000    ,2432902008176640000);';

EXEC(@t);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e81cfd583d59eb57856b2fca3a5c943c)**

Comment: Well done!  But will you accept Martin Smith's challenge excluding the letter S?  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Challenge Accepted. Just exchange `SELECT` with `PRINT`  And CHOOSE will have to go to nested `IIF` :)

Comment: You'll need to change those `AS` aliases to a `=` too. ;)

Comment: Although `IIF()` can only be nested 10 times, you can nest on both the `THEN` and the `ELSE` side, resulting in many more options for Martin Smith's variant.

Answer (score 5):

I would use simple arithmetic:

```
set @fact = exp(log(@fact) + log(@given_number));
```

In fact, you can just add the logs in the loop, but why use a `while` loop?

```
with f as (
      select @given_number as n
      union all
      select n -1
      from f
      where n > 1
     )
select exp(sum(log(f.n)))
from f;
```

This has the nice feature that it is limited to the range of floating point values rather than integers.

Comment: Huh, a serious answer to what I thought was an off-the-cuff challenge

Comment: @Gordon I like the approach with logarithm (exchanging multiplication with sum) . 2 things: Missing `)`: `exp(sum(log(f.n)))` and I would add `CEILING`. **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f05a4b045f7f3bed7257a61508ae71da)**

Comment: @lad2025 . . . The problem with `ceiling()` is that it restricts the output to whatever can fit into an integer.  That might be sufficient, but I like the support of larger values.

Answer (score 0):

> Query for finding factorial without using * operator in T-SQL

```
declare @Given_number int=7;
declare @y int=0;
declare @z int=0;
declare @a int=@given_number;
declare @b int=@given_number;
declare @i int=@a;
while(@i>1)
begin
declare @j int=1;
while(@j<@i)
begin
set @z=@b+@y;
set @y=@z;
set @j=@j+1;
end
set @b=@z;
set @y=0;
set @i=@i-1;
end 
select @z as 'Factorial'
```