# Evaluate factorial(n) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I evaluate a math expression like `k!` in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: If you mean factorial you could write a custom function to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504932/sql-functions-factorial for example.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to evaluate a mathematical expression at the database level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Functions - factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504932/sql-functions-factorial)

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - which one is it??

Comment: The largest integral type SQL Server supports can only hold the results of 33! at most, so the easiest way is actually a function that just consults a constant lookup table. If you're OK with floating-point approximations you could go further...

Answer (score 1):

I really think it's a bad idea to compute a factorial in SQL Server, but if you must:

```
with pair (n, f) as (
  select 0 as n, 1 as f
  union all
  select p.n + 1 as n, p.f * (p.n + 1) from pair p 
    where p.n < 5 -- factorial of 5
)
select f from pair where n = 5; -- factorial of 5
```

You need to place the value of `N` twice there. Result:

```
f
---
120
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Factorial ( @i int )

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i  int

    IF @i <= 1
        SET @i = 1
    ELSE
        SET @i = @i * Factorial( @i - 1 )
RETURN (@i)
END
```